# how to manage gpu RAM in google colab?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

When I run some DL models written with PyTorch I have the error:

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 108.00 MiB (GPU 0;
> 14.73 GiB total capacity; 13.68 GiB already allocated; 11.88 MiB free; 13.78 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch).

It's happened when I try to track some bugs and run cell over and over.
Are there some lifehacks to avoid it?

Here is an example of code (I marked out cells in google colab):

```py
def train(...):
  ...
  assert False
  ...
```

```py
model = SegNet().to(device)
```

```py
max_epochs = 20
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=10e-5)
train(model, optim, bce_loss, max_epochs, data_tr, data_val)
```

I found operator `del` so I could make

```py
del model
```

after used `model`. But how I can manage memory using after manual or some error `assert`?

Comment: You did not give any information or code. So the only advise to give is to use less CPU RAM.

Comment: @KlausD. I think you meant "GPU RAM"?

Answer (score 0):

Operator `del X_batch` right after `y_pred = model(X_batch...)` helps me a little. Function `.backward()` uses the biggest bunch of RAM but I can do nothing with it. I suppose colab.google isn't relevant to RAM using.